# Copy folder from container to host after docker run

Tags: linux, docker, containers, copying

I have an image that will create a catalog after running the container. What I want to do is to run the container with mounted volume and after running it I want to copy this catalog to the mounted host folder.

Tried several ways but couldn't get it done. Most of the documentation talks about docker cp or docker volumes.

What I want to do is to run:

`docker run -t -d -v test/:/test`

and then when I would create any file in test dir in the container it will appear in the test folder on the host.

CP works fine but it's manual. I want to just run the container and it will copy necessary files from inside to mounted directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `docker run -v` option is the right way.  Note, however, that the host-side path needs to be an absolute path, so the most common (Linux/Unix Bourne shell) syntax is

```bash
docker run -v "$PWD/test:/test" ...
```

If you're using Docker Compose, its `volumes:` option does accept relative paths, which are considered relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file.

The important caveats with this approach is that the container directory `/test` must not be the directory that contains the application code, and that the permissions and *numeric* ownership of the host directory propagate into the mounted volume.  It's also common to run the container with the numeric user ID that the current host user has; there is no requirement to "create the user" in the container, and something of an anti-pattern to build a specific user ID in the image.

A complete extended command might look like:

```bash
docker run \
  -d \                    # in the background
  -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \  # with the host user and group IDs
  -v "$PWD/test:/test" \  # with a bind mount
  the-image \
  /app/run_tests -o /test/catalog.json  # overriding the command
                                        # with specific container paths
```